# Work with multiple environments/variables in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

We're using terraform to spin up our infrastructure within AWS and we have 3 separate environments: Dev, Stage and Prod

Dev : Requires - public, private1a, privatedb and privatedb2 subnets
Stage & Prod : Requires - public, private_1a, private_1b, privatedb and privatedb2 subnets

I have main.tf, variables, dev.tfvars, stage.tfvars and prod.tfvars. I'm trying to understand as of how can I use main.tf file that I'm currently using for dev environment and create resources required for stage and prod using .tfvars files.

terraform apply -var-file=dev.tfvars

terraform apply -var-file=stage.tfvars (this should create subnet private_1b in addition to the other subnets)

terraform apply -var-file=prod.tfvars (this should create subnet private_1b in addition to the other subnets)

Please let me know if you need further clarification.

Thanks,

Answer (score 9):

What you are trying to do is indeed the correct approach. You will also have to make use of [terraform workspaces](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html).

> Terraform starts with a single workspace named "default". This
>   workspace is special both because it is the default and also because
>   it cannot ever be deleted. If you've never explicitly used workspaces,
>   then you've only ever worked on the "default" workspace.
>
> Workspaces are managed with the terraform workspace set of commands.
>   To create a new workspace and switch to it, you can use terraform
>   workspace new; to switch environments you can use terraform workspace
>   select; etc.

In essence this means you will have a workspace for each environment you have.

Lets see with some examples.

I have the following files:

1. **main.tf**
2. **variables.tf**
3. **dev.tfvars**
4. **production.tfvars**

**main.tf**

This file contains the VPC module 9Can be any resource ofc). We call the variables via the var. function:

```
module "vpc" {
  source          = "modules/vpc"
  cidr_block      = "${var.vpc_cidr_block}"
  subnets_private = "${var.vpc_subnets_private}"
  subnets_public  = "${var.vpc_subnets_public}"
}
```

**variables.tf**

This file contains all our variables. Please do not that we do not assign **default** here, this will make sure we are 100% certain that we are using the variables from the .tfvars files.

```
variable "vpc_cidr_block" {}

variable "vpc_subnets_private" {
  type = "list"
}

variable "vpc_subnets_public" {
  type = "list"
}
```

That's basically it. Our .tfvars file will look like this:

**dev.tfvars**

```
vpc_cidr_block = "10.40.0.0/16"
vpc_subnets_private = ["10.40.0.0/19", "10.40.64.0/19", "10.40.128.0/19"]
vpc_subnets_public = ["10.40.32.0/20", "10.40.96.0/20", "10.40.160.0/20"]
```

**production.tfvars**

```
vpc_cidr_block = "10.30.0.0/16"
vpc_subnets_private = ["10.30.0.0/19", "10.30.64.0/19", "10.30.128.0/19"]
vpc_subnets_public = ["10.30.32.0/20", "10.30.96.0/20", "10.30.160.0/20"]
```

If I would like to run terraform for my dev environment, these are the commands I would use (Assuming the workspaces are already created, see [Terraform workspace docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html)):

1. Select the dev environment: `terraform workspace select dev`
2. Run a plan to see the changes: `terraform plan -var-file=dev.tfvars -out=plan.out`
3. Apply the changes: `terraform apply plan.out`

You can replicate this for as many environments as you like.

Comment: Did not know about workspaces. I already have resources created using my dev.tfvars but when I have created a new workspace dev and have applied it using plan.out like you have suggested above. The resources got created again even after the same VPC CIDR and subnets already exists. How would that be possible?

Comment: Also when we create 4 servers using count, how can I label the servers dla(should get the value from dev.tfvars)-server-%01d and also assign 2 servers to 1a AZ and the other 2 to 1b AZ?

Comment: Because your dev environment is currently created in the 'Default' Workspace. Terraform sees every workspace as a clean sheet. At this time it is not possible to rename workspaces in terraform. You could move the resources, (terraform import & terraform state rm) but that's rather time consuming

Comment: You could use a map and then work with lookups. if you could post it in a separate question I would be happy to give an example there

Comment: Here you go https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51156262/terraform-how-to-append-the-server-count-and-assign-servers-to-multiple-azs

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51196693/terraform-how-to-create-multiple-aws-subnets-from-one-resource-block

Comment: The document linked in this answer explicitly states that workspaces aren't a suitable way to separate different environments like staging and production: `In particular, organizations commonly want to create a strong separation between multiple deployments of the same infrastructure serving different development stages (e.g. staging vs. production) or different internal teams. In this case, the backend used for each deployment often belongs to that deployment, with different credentials and access controls. Named workspaces are not a suitable isolation mechanism for this scenario.`