# Terraform: How to append the server count and assign servers to multiple AZ's?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

**main.tf**

```
resource "aws_instance" "service" {
  ami           = "${lookup(var.aws_winamis, var.awsregion)}"
  count         = "${var.count}"
  key_name      = "${var.key_name}"
  instance_type = "t2.medium"
  subnet_id     = "${aws_subnet.private.id}"
  # private_ip    = "${lookup(var.server_instance_ips, count.index)}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_group.private-sg.id}"]
  associate_public_ip_address = false
  availability_zone           = "${var.awsregion}a"
  tags {
    Name        = "${format("server-%01d", count.index + 1)}"
    Environment = "${var.environment}"
  }
}
```

**Variable.tf**

```
variable "awsregion" {default =""}
variable "count" {default = ""}
variable "server_instance_ips" {default = ""}
```

**dev.tfvars**

```
server_instance_ips = ["10.0.2.25", "10.0.2.26"] #doesn't work as a list but works with single IP address
count = "4"
awsregion = "us-east-1"
```

I want the servers to have tags - `dla-server-1`/`2`/`3`/`4` after they're created but with my above code I can only do `server-1`/`2`/`3`/`4` but not `dla`/`sla`/`pla` depending on the environments; IP addresses are randomly assigned to the servers as I'm not able to pass the list of IP's and lastly, how can I create servers in different AZ's i.e. 2 servers in AZ1a and 2 servers in AZ1b?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first answer is easy: add the prefix in the tag name.

```
tags {
  Name        = "${var.environment}-${format("server-%01d", count.index + 1)}"
  Environment = "${var.environment}"
}
```

You need to specify the type of the variable to be a list:

```
variable "server_instance_ips"
{
  type = "list"
  default = []
}
```

The last question can be solved in many ways, I would go for something similar

```
availability_zone = "${data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]}"
```

Comment: Instead of using ${var.environment} I would advise you use ${terraform.workspace}

Comment: @giulio vian, I'm getting the following error.
Error: resource 'aws_subnet.private' config: unknown resource 'data.aws_availability_zones.available' referenced in variable data.aws_availability_zones.available.names
**main.tf**

`resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  vpc_id                  = "${aws_vpc.vpcname.id}"
  cidr_block              = "${var.private_subnet}"
  availability_zone       = "${data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]}"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false

  tags {
    Name        = "${var.private}"
    Environment = "${terraform.workspace}"
  }
}`

Comment: **variable.tf**

`variable "aws_availability_zones" {
  default = [
    "us-east-1a",
    "us-east-1b",
    "us-east-1c",
    "us-east-1e"
  ]
  type = "list"
}`

Comment: You need to declare data sources `data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}`
see https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/availability_zones.html

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thanks!!

Declared data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {} in **main.tf** and it worked.

One last question, I want to create multiple private subnets from one resource block and I'm doing the following which doesn't work.

Comment: **main.tf**

`
resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  vpc_id                  = "${aws_vpc.vpcname.id}"
  cidr_block              = "${var.private_subnet}"
  availability_zone       = "${data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]}"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false

  tags {
    Name        = "${var.private}"
    Environment = "${terraform.workspace}"
  }
}
`

Comment: **variable**

`variable "private_subnet" {
  type    = "list"
  default = []
}
`
** dev.tfvars**

`
private_subnet = ["10.0.2.0/24", "10.0.3.0/24"] `

Error: aws_subnet.private: cidr_block must be a single value, not a list

Comment: StackOverflow is not a forum: your questions should be specific and not use the comments for solving issue unrelated to the original post. I suggest to take this https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Sorry !! I'm new to stackoverflow.
How can I create multiple subnets from one resource block?
I have listed my main.tf, variable.tf and dev.tfvars files above.

Comment: If I answered your original question, mark it as answered. If you have additional unrelated questions, create new ones. Do not use the original.
and TAKE THE TOUR https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174442/discussion-between-karthik-and-giulio-vian).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51196693/terraform-how-to-create-multiple-aws-subnets-from-one-resource-block

Comment: This is the error I get when I assign service_instance_ips = ["10.0.2.25", "10.0.2.26"] 
Error: aws_instance.service[0]: private_ip must be a single value, not a list