# Terraform: How to create multiple aws subnets from one resource block?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to create multiple subnets from one resource block and I get the following error

> Error: aws_subnet.private: cidr_block must be a single value, not a list

**main.tf**

```
resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  vpc_id                  = "${aws_vpc.vpcname.id}"
  cidr_block              = "${var.private_subnet}"
  availability_zone       = "${data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]}"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false

  tags {
    Name        = "${var.private}"
    Environment = "${terraform.workspace}"
  }
}
```

**variable.tf**

```
variable "private_subnet" {
  type    = "list"
  default = []
}
```

**dev.tfvars**

```
private_subnet = ["10.0.2.0/24", "10.0.3.0/24"]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to create multiple `aws_subnet` resources by utilitizing the `count` argument to create one resource for each entry in your `var.private_subnet` list:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  count                   = "${length(var.private_subnet)}"
  vpc_id                  = "${aws_vpc.vpcname.id}"
  cidr_block              = "${var.private_subnet[count.index]}"
  availability_zone       = "${data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]}"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false
}
```

This expands the single `aws_subnet` resource into two, each with slightly different values based on the enumeration of `count` when each resource block is evaluated by terraform.

Comment: This worked but the other resource block code that's dependent on private subnet listed below doesn't work.

`resource "aws_nat_gateway" "nat" {
  allocation_id = "${aws_eip.eipname.id}"
  subnet_id     = "${aws_subnet.private.id}"
  depends_on    = ["aws_internet_gateway.gw"]

  tags {
    Name        = "${var.natgateway}"
    Environment = "${terraform.workspace}"
  }
}`

Answer (score 1):

`private_subnet` is a list, so you should pick a single element, e.g.

`cidr_block = "${element(var.private_subnet,count.index)}"`

Answer (score 0):

also add data module to get the availability zones for a region

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "available" {}
```

e.g.

```
availability_zone       = "${data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]}"
```